# AutoLayout setup for a UITableView within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to show multiple labels in my main `UITableViewCell`, for which I am trying to use a `UITableView` within the cell. Now I have setup all the delegates and datasources properly, and the data is coming in right. But the inner `UITableView` has a dynamic number of cells, and a dynamic height respectively.

What I want is, to have an autolayout constraints setup, which allows my main `UITableViewCell` to resize as per it's inner `UITableView`.

Currently what's happening is, the inner `tableView` loads data perfectly, but does not resize as per the data, due to which the main cell can also not resize.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: That sounds extremely strange ... I would suggest changing the interface. However, I don't think it's possible but since you (have to) know the number of cells inside the table view of the main table view (huh) you could set the height in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 1):

Autolayout can not calculate the height of uitableview that inside cell because uitableview scroll inside there fore you can calculate the heigth required for your uitableview According to no. Of rows and content and then set this calculated height . in heightForRowAtIndexPath for main cell .